# How select options from a smart-select?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get all the options from a dropdown with Selenium but I get the exception that the Select module does not work with smart-select. Is there any way to get the values of this dropdown with selenium?

`Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <smart-select>`

Edit:
This is the HTML:

```html
<smart-select _ngcontent-xhq-c24="" class="col-3" ng-reflect-list="[object Object],[object Object">
  <div tabindex="3" class="search-select" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
    <div class="custom-select" ng-reflect-klass="custom-select" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
      <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
       <span>6. Element 6</span>
      <!--bindings={}-->
      <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"

    </div>
    <div class="select-drop">
      <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"

      <ul class="select-results">
        <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"

        <li ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"> 1. Element 1 </li>
        <li ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"> 2. Element 2 </li>
        <li ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"> 3. Element 3 </li>
        <li ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"> 4. Element 4 </li>
        <li ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"> 5. Element 5 </li>
        <li class="option-selected" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"> 6. Element 6 </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--bindings={}
  <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"

</smart-select>
```

Comment: Could you show the code please? Also, the website link if it is ok to share here

Comment: Hi @AnandGautam i can't share the website, but i can post de xpath of the select. The code is a sample from the Select(webdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_select))

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.